# SyntaxError when create django project

Tags: python, django

When I try to create a django project with python3.6, this error raises:

```
Error creating Django application: Error on python side. Exit code: 1, err: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm 2017.3\helpers\pycharm\_jb_django_project_creator.py", line 12, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line(argv=["django-admin", "startproject", project_name, path])
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\__init__.py", line 15, in setup
    from django.utils.log import configure_logging
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\utils\log.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\views\debug.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import Resolver404, resolve
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.http import Http404
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\http\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.http.response import (
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\http\response.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\core\serializers\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q, QuerySet, Prefetch  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\query.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.db.models import sql
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\sql\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\sql\subqueries.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query_utils import Q
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.db.backends import utils
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.utils.timezone import utc
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.18-py3.6.egg\django\utils\timezone.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pytz
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytz\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pytz.lazy import LazyDict, LazyList, LazySet
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytz\lazy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from UserDict import DictMixin
  File "C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\UserDict.py", line 167
    raise TypeError, "pop expected at most 2 arguments, got "\
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And there are both python2.7 and 3.6 on my computer. When I create a django project with python2.7, there is no any problem. This error only raises when I use python3.6 as interpreter.

Could anybody tell me how to solve it?

Thanks for your attention and time.

Comment: is your django version compatible with python 3.6?

Comment: There's no module `UserDict` in Python 3, only in Python 2. Somehow, your setup is corrupted, and there is a Python 2 module in your Python 3 library directory.

Comment: @johnII I think it does. Because I have tried django 1.8, 2.0 and the newest 2.1, and by both pip and manully installation.

Comment: @Evert Yes I saw a similar explanation on Github, but he didn't say how to fix it. Can you give me some specific advice to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably the best is to remove that whole directory (the complete `Python36` directory) and reinstall Python 3.6. You *might* get away with just removing the `UserDict.py*` file(s), but there may be other version 2 files lying around in that directory. And just re-installing without deleting the directory may simply overwrite files, but leave (other) existing files in place (disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Python installations on Windows).